# Cython : memory-efficient padding of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I have a M×N numpy array. Before a FFT I need to pad it with zeros to get a (M+K)×(N+K) array where the M and N first indices are the original data and the K last indices along each dimension are zeros.

Using Cython, is there an efficient way to do so without loosing the `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2]` type ?

Comment: I think the most memory-efficient would be to use `ndarray.resize` and then moving the data within the array to the correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of padding an array is to create a target of the right size, and copy values:

```
In [137]: M,N,K = 10,20,5
In [138]: source = np.arange(M*N).reshape(M,N)
In [139]: target = np.zeros((M+K, N+K), dtype=source.dtype)
In [140]: target[:M, :N] = source
```

You can't get any more memory efficient than that.

I don't see how `cython` will help with memory use, since memory use is determined by the size of source and target arrays, not the coping method.

I'm not even sure it will be faster, especially if you want `target` to be a numpy array that can be used in interpreted Python.  If both source and target are typed memoryview, the copy might be faster, but we'd have to test that.

Comment: That's what I ended up to do. Thanks ! Cython is not used for that purpose, but I need this feature inside a Cython module.

Answer (score 0):

The following will turn your array into a padded version without changing its type:

```
array = np.hstack((array,np.zeros((np.size(array,0),K))))
array = np.vstack((array,np.zeros((K,np.size(array,1)))))
```